# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+2}{n^2+4n-7}\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^n $ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Does the following series converge, does it converge absolutely?
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+2}{n^2+4n-7}\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^n $$

Now I thought about using Dirichlets Test of Uniform Convergence.

I know that $|\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{4}{7})^n|\leq M < \infty$.

I am left to show that if $\frac{n+2}{n^2+4n-7} \rightarrow 0$ uniformly then my whole series converge uniformly?

**What does uniform convergence of series mean?**

I know that it means partial summs converge uniformly, but what is it in lazy mans terms? Does it imply absolute convergence?

Comment: This problem will succumb to a simple Comparison Test.   Give it a try.

Comment: It will be easier the other way around, $\forall n \geq 2,  \frac{n+2}{n^2+4n-7} \leq 1$. Then use the convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^N (\frac{4}{7})^n$

Comment: Root test is also good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. One may just observe that
$$0\leq \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n+2}{n^2+4n-7}\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^n\leq \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^n<\infty.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $\dfrac{n+2}{n^2+4n-7} < 1 (n \geq 3) $  and  $\left|\dfrac{4}{7}\right| < 1$